# Help wit install & use GeForce RTX 2070 on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I am new to the machines with more power and I got this time a Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070 and I really don't know hot to install and choose it. I tried it a lot of times with a lot of different tutorials, but I does not work.
When I use the Additional Software GUI variable I get nvidia-detector-crash error at every bootup.
So I am now using the xorg opensource driver which is not provinding me the power I need. And although in my Settings>About>Graphics is Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) / Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) listed.

How can I change it and install the Graphics Card which I really have in my machine?
I have really a very hard time to fix this issue...

System info: Razer Blade 15 laptop with Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 i7 9th Gen with NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070

Comment: Make sure that your monitor is plugged into the graphics card and not your motherboard.  It may not be required, but it is best practice to reinstall the operating system when making a significant hardware change.

Comment: I have tried it several times, but everytime the same. No mater which Linux OS it is.
And I am using it on a Laptop. Could it be that I have to do some chnages in the BIOS?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the full output of those.  You can delete those crash file output you added.  That is the output from the actual `.crash` file.  Try deleting all crash files `sudo rm /var/crash/*` and reboot then see if they come back.

Comment: I actually got                   nvidia-dkms-460.0.crash           as well.
I will try to reboot it now.

Comment: I just rebooted and waited some seconds. I got the error again.. 
_usr_bin_nvidia-detector.1000.crash

Comment: Delete your two answers below as that will not help us.  That info should go to developers when it is uploaded so that they can fix it, you shouldn't have to do anything as it probably did it on its own.  I made the changes to your question about your system info and gave you an upvote to help you along your way.  I wish I had a laptop like yours to help troubleshoot your problem, but I don't so I will not be anymore help from here on.  Hopefully someone has the same configuration and will know.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it.